cURL File upload. File of 0 byte is getting uploaded
I am trying to upload a file to webserver using cURL, -H headers are are used to provide the details of the content, there are three parameters that I have to pass.
below is the raw header
--data-raw ^"--myBoundry^
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="App" ^
execute=location/in/the/server/^
--myBoundry^
Content-Disposition: form-data;name="file";filename="**foo.csv**"^
Content-Type: text/csv^
^
^
--myBoundry^
Content-Disposition: forma-data;name="directory"^
^/upload/location/"^
--myBoundry--^
^"

I can see the file in the server, but the size is always 0.
I wonder where curl is expecting foo.csv to be, the same location where we run the curl script from or somewhere else.
have already tried @/full/local/path/foo.csv, but the result was the same.
New to cURL, would help if someone could point me in the right direction.
Tried giving the full path to the local file, that did not work.

This question is similar to: Using cURL to upload POST data with files. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also: Correct curl command for uploading local file to url
